# The ContT Monad: Putting the pieces together

Tags: haskell, continuations, callcc

**Preamble**

I am trying to wrap my head around how to actually use `ContT` and `callCC` for something useful. I'm having trouble following information and control flows around the the code. (but, isn't that the point of a continuation?)

There are a lot of different ways to move pieces around with this monad and a small handful of not very straight forward combinators. I will confess that I'm still uncomfortable with my understanding of how ContT works, but I will point to what I have read so far:

- [Haskell/Continuation passing style](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style)
- [How and why does the Haskell Cont monad work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3322540/how-and-why-does-the-haskell-cont-monad-work)
- [Understanding Haskell callCC examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536700/understanding-haskell-callcc-examples/20542256#20542256)
- [Goto in Haskell: Can anyone explain this seemingly insane effect of continuation monad usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193876/goto-in-haskell-can-anyone-explain-this-seemingly-insane-effect-of-continuation/5203603#5203603)
- [How to interpret callCC in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451022/how-to-interpret-callcc-in-haskell)
- [Parsec Generally](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/parsec-generally.xhtml) (the article that started me down this path)

What I would like to do is post a psudo-code example then ask some questions about it.  This represents the typical look of code using ContT

**Psudo-Code**

```
type MyMonad r = ContT r (State SomeState)

main = do
  runState s_init $ runContT block print

block :: MyMonad r a0
block = do
  before_callcc
  output <- callCC $ \k -> do
    rval <- inner_block
    return rval
  after_callcc
```

**Questions**

1. What determines the value and type of `output`?
2. What does the `b` mean in the type of `k`?
3. Where does the value given to `k` go?
4. When is `inner_block` run? What version of the state does it see?
5. Where does `rval` go and what its type?
6. What is the relationship between `k` and `rval`?
7. What happens when I apply `k` a) in `inner_block`, b) in `after_callcc`, c) outside of `block`?
8. What is the version of the state in each of the above?
9. What do I need to do to get `k` out of `block`?
10. Can I put `k` into the state?

---

**Color Coded for easier reading**

[image: Color Coded example]

Comment: I know you have already read a lot, but this is another excellent resource on that: http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/12/the-continuation-monad.html

Comment: Sibi, I like it except there is no mention of callCC. Also, [this][http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/04/how-continuation-monad-works.html] was linked and was most edifying.

Comment: Some of these questions ask "Can I?" Have you tried?

Comment: Please revise the title as you deem fit ("pieces of the ?").

Comment: dfeuer, yes and I cannot get it to type check.  Does that mean that it cannot be done or merely that I am not doing it correctly?

Comment: You may find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25382352/477476) useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. What determines the value and type of `output`?

It will be of the same type as `rval`. The value will also be the same, unless `inner_block` uses `k someValue` to escape the rest of the block. In that case, `output` will be `someValue`.

> 2. What does the `b` mean in the type of `k`?

Roughly, `b` can be understood as "anything at all". That is, if `inner_block` is

```
...
v <- k someValue
use v
```

then `v :: b`. However, `k someValue` will never run the rest of the block since it will exit the `callCC` immediately. So, no concrete value for `v` will be ever returned. Because of this `v` can have any type: it does not matter if `use` requires a `String` or an `Int` -- it's not being executed anyway.

> 3. Where does the value given to `k` go?

As soon as the inner block runs `k someValue` the value is returned by the `callCC` as `output`, and the rest of the block is skipped.

> 4. When is `inner_block` run? What version of the state does it see?

It is run as `callCC` is called, and sees the same state as we had at that point.

> 5. Where does `rval` go and what its type?

Into `output`. Same type.

> 6. What is the relationship between `k` and `rval`?

`rval` has the same type as the argument of `k`.

> 7. What happens when I apply `k` a) in `inner_block`, b) in `after_callcc`, c) outside of `block`?

a) See above.
b) `k` is out of scope in `after_callcc`.
c) Also out of scope.

> 8. What is the version of the state in each of the above?

The state is the "current" one. (I am not sure what you exactly are asking for here)

> 9. What do I need to do to get `k` out of `block`?

A recursive type is needed here, I guess. Here's an attempt:

```
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans

type SomeState = String
type MyMonad r = ContT r (State SomeState)

newtype K a b r = K ((K a b r, a) -> MyMonad r b)

main = do
  print $ flip runState "init" $ runContT block return

block :: MyMonad r Int
block = do
  lift $ modify (++ ":start")
  (K myK, output) <- callCC $ \k -> do
    s <- lift $ get
    lift $ modify (++ ":inner(" ++ show (length s) ++")")
    return (K k, 10)
  lift $ modify (++ ":output=" ++ show output)
  s <- lift $ get
  when (length s <50) $ myK (K myK, output+1)
  return 5
```

This prints

```
(5,"init:start:inner(10):output=10:output=11:output=12")
```

> 10. Can I put `k` into the state?

I believe you need a recursive type for that, too.

Comment: You have shown admirable focus in managing to write a sensible answer to *fourteen* questions. I started two separate drafts, but gave up on both.

Comment: @duplode To keep it short, I did not really cover all the tricky cases, e.g. when `k` outlives its own `callCC`. I guess the OP is interested in those cases, which I dodged a bit.